# How to modify a link's href so it submits form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, forms

I am working on an web page which I am templating with EJS. Each row has its own form and a number of form elements (all disabled); row ends with a icon serves as a link.

What I want to do is when that icon is clicked, the icon changes to a 'tick' icon and have all form elements on that row gets enabled. So far so good...

However, after this transition, I want the link (now with a 'tick' icon) to be able to submit the form if clicked. I failed to do that.

Where I have the icon in the EJS template:

```
<a href="#" onclick="adjustActionIcons('<%=i%>')" id="link<%=i%>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="editIcon<%=i%>"></span></a>
```

The function called after the click:

```
function adjustActionIcons(id) {
document.getElementById("dropDown" + id).removeAttribute("disabled");
document.getElementById("Text" + id).removeAttribute("disabled");
document.getElementById("editIcon" + id).className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok";
// ?????
}
```

How can I change the href attribute replaced by a form submit function/trigger? Or any other approach to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Call the form submit method in your click handler …?

Comment: Add setTimeout function to submit the form(for example the id of the form is id_frm, then document.getElementById('id_frm').submit()).In this way, the transition and the submit function can work asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you can extend the `onclick` function on your elements - and place a hidden submit button next to it, then modify code like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="adjustActionIcons('<%=i%>');$(this).next().trigger('click');" id="link<%=i%>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="editIcon<%=i%>"></span></a>
<button type="submit" style="display:none"></button>
```

This will submit the forms that the anchor tags are located in respectively.

*PS: As an alternative you can also just find the closest form element and call the submit trigger on that. Let me know if you need that info.*

**EDIT:** Replace that one line with

```
$(this).closest('form').submit();
```

If you are still struggling perhaps show the markup up untill the actual form.

Comment: Thanks, I pasted the code however the editor shows 'identifier expected' after the word 'function' - used it as 'function test()' Also made a few changes. 'adjustActionIcons' functions is not called at all. (using the original and also during a few of my variations) What am I missing please?

Comment: I edited the answer, the <code>function () {}</code> call is completely wrong. My bad. The rest should work though. Keep me posted

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work as is: after first click the image changes and elements enabled but immediately after, everything gets reset. I added "return false;" after function call which seems to stop the immediate change. But still, the new link does not submit the form. I'll work on it more and hopefully come back with results...

Comment: Latest version did not work either. I realized doing everything on one page will be too complicated for me especially with these simulated submits. I've moved the view and edit to separate pages and I achieved my goal. However, I believe what I am trying to do initially is what's being done around in the professional web sites, right? Thank you for the guidance